copy an existing transaction
in case I copy an existing transaction (I mean copy everything of an transaction fromAdress, toAddres, amount, signature, ...) and try to broadcast it, I know that It will fail because the transaction is exist before. My question is: Is bitcoin have to traverse to all transaction on all block before to see that my transaction is exist before, I think that is just very inefficient

This question is similar to: How does the transaction signature prevent transaction duplication?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Is bitcoin have to traverse to all transaction on all block before to see that my transaction is exist before

No.
Nodes such as Bitcoin Core maintain a list of unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs). When verifying a transaction they check that its inputs are all in their UTXO set. Transaction outputs referenced as inputs to earlier transactions will no longer be in the UTXO set.
